# Checking the prerequisites for an app while clicking an app in home screen

Tags: java, android

I am working on Android app which includes MapActivity, requires internet connectivity and location services. With the help of intents i can check the availability of internet and location services in the first activity(showing popup's using alertdialog).
 Is there any way to check the availability of internet and location services while launching an app(clicking the app in home screen). Since i want to eliminate the alertdialog's for checking both the things in my login activity.
ie) Is there any way in android to register the intents and mark it mandatory so that android framework itself blocks my app from launching.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed, u can use the following code to check if the phone is connected to INTERNET, and if not u can terminate the application or display a appropriate message.

public boolean isOnline() {

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {

    Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
    int exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
    return (exitValue == 0);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return false;
```

}

The ip address here is of Google, u can replace it with your own server. It return true if connected and false otherwise.The below code can be used to check the location permissions

if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //do something here (terminate or a message)
}

Comment: I have to write the above piece of code in some activity ie) first activity. Also you should not use process in android, which is not recommended. My expectation is that while launching i have to block.

Comment: So u don't want the application to even start? like not even a splash-screen?

Comment: exactly! thats what i need!